# android splitActionBarWhenNarrow doent work

Tags: android

currently im doint something like a facebook "pinboard" so i made ActionBarActivity with some tabs to seperate stuff. I used a ListFragment to show the posts. Everything is working fine. Now i want a actionBar(or just tabs) on the bottom part of the app. i found that splitActionBarWhenNarrow could solve it...but it doesnt. It just wont split even if i put 20 tabs into the bar... it just gets smth. like a slide/swipe option. Anyone of you knows how to solve it or is there a different way then splitActionBarWhenNarrow ?
Im not adding my tabs via the menu.xml btw. Here are my files:

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.forbiddencodex.customlistview" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hides action bar title

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` is not supported by either `appcompat-v7` or Android 5.0+.

Second, `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` does not put tabs on the bottom on any version of Android.

Third, you do not control where the action bar tabs go, or whether they are even tabs (versus a `Spinner`), as that is up to the action bar implementation.

Fourth, action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0. Google would like you to use some other tab option, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I know its deprecated but when i want it for earlier versions i have to use it right? Or should i still use the newer ones and import libraries? So how can i make tabs appear on the bottom?:O

Comment: @zooky: "I know its deprecated but when i want it for earlier versions i have to use it right?" -- if you use the native action bar (not `appcompat-v7`), you can have a split action bar in API Level 11 through 20. "So how can i make tabs appear on the bottom?" -- bottom tabs are not part of the Android design aesthetic, and action bar tabs cannot go on the bottom. You are welcome to investigate third-party tab solutions for one that might work on the bottom.

Comment: Thx 4 the help :) i just wanted to do smth like the facebook app uses for actions like "post" etc. they have a bar at the bottom which only appears when u are at the top of the pinboard and disappears when u scroll down. But maybe i could simply use a layout and put buttons ins and i only show it when im at the top..this might work.